# AngularJS ng is ignored

Tags: angularjs, select, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click, ng-options

i'm developing an app that should have a form with select boxes that are populated dinamically with JSON arrays and the options depends of the choose option in the before select.

My problem is that the controller is correctly executed but the select options are not populated from the controller, there are empty.

And seems the the ng directives are always ignored

Also the ng-click directive in the button is ignored.

Can someone help me to solve it?

Thank's

```js
angular.module('App', []) .controller('TimesController', function ($http) {
            console.log("JavaScript Function");
            var attivita = <?php echo json_encode($cod_attivita); ?>;
            var config = {
      transformResponse: function (data, headers) {
        var result = {
          events: [],
          events2: [],
          events3: [],
          schedules: [],
          schedules2: [],
          schedules3: []
        };
        var events = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(events);
        var events2 = JSON.parse(data);
        var events3 = JSON.parse(data);
        var dates = [];
        var sedi = [];
        var professionisti = [];
        console.log("qua3");
        for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
          if (dates.indexOf(events[i].day) === -1) {
            var date = events[i].day;
            dates.push(date);
            result.events.push({
              date: date
            });
          }
          if (sedi.indexOf(events[i].sede) === -1) {
            var sede = events[i].sede;
            sedi.push(sede);
            result.events2.push({
              sede: sede
            });
          }
          if (professionisti.indexOf(events[i].professionista) === -1) {
            var professionista = events[i].professionista;
            professionisti.push(professionista);
            result.events3.push({
              professionista: professionista
            });
          }
          var a = 0;
          var found = false;
          while (a < result.schedules2.length) {
              if (events[i].sede === result.schedules2[a].sede && events[i].professionista === result.schedules2[a].professionista) {
                  found = true;
              }
              a++;
          }
          if (found == false) {
              result.schedules2.push({
                sede: events[i].sede,
                professionista: events[i].professionista
              });
          }
          var a = 0;
          var found = false;
          while (a < result.schedules3.length) {
              if (events[i].sede === result.schedules3[a].sede && events[i].professionista === result.schedules3[a].professionista && events[i].day === result.schedules3[a].date) {
                  found = true;
              }
              a++;
          }
          if (found == false) {
              console.log("OLEE");
              result.schedules3.push({
                sede: events[i].sede,
                professionista: events[i].professionista,
                date: events[i].day
              });
          }
          result.schedules.push({
            sede: events[i].sede,
            professionista: events[i].professionista,
            date: events[i].day,
            time: events[i].time
            //console.log("qua4");
          });
        }
        console.log(result);
        return result;
      }
    };
    var email = "assistenza@pgdue.com";
    var link = 'http://sviluppo.pgdue.com/shuttle/admin/app-service/get-orari?e='+email+"&attivita="+attivita;
    console.log(link);
    return $http.get(link, config)
      .then(getEventsCompleted)
      .catch(getEventsFailed);
    function getEventsCompleted(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
      return response.data;
      console.log(response.data);
    }

    function getEventsFailed(error) {
      console.error(error);
    }

    var submit = function () {
        console.log("submit function");
    }
        })
```

```html
<div ng-app="App">
    <div align="center" ng-controller="TimesController as ctrl">
        <p style="font-size: 22px;">Inserisci appuntamento</p>
        <br>
        <div class="list" align="center">
                <div class="input-label">
                </div>
                <select style="width: 75%;" ng-options="event as event.sede for event in ctrl.data.events2" ng-model="ctrl.form.sede">
                    <option value="" disabled>Seleziona sede</option>
                </select>
        </div><br>
        <div class="list" align="center">
                <div class="input-label">
                </div>
                <select style="width: 75%;" ng-options="schedule as schedule.professionista for schedule in ctrl.data.schedules2| filter: { sede: ctrl.form.sede.sede}" ng-model="ctrl.form.professionista" ng-disabled="!ctrl.form.sede">
                    <option value="" disabled>Seleziona professionista</option>
                </select>
        </div><br>
        <div class="list" align="center">
                <div class="input-label">
                </div>
                <select style="width: 75%;" ng-options="schedule as schedule.date for schedule in ctrl.data.schedules3| filter: { professionista: ctrl.form.professionista.professionista, sede: ctrl.form.sede.sede}" ng-model="ctrl.form.giorno" ng-disabled="!ctrl.form.professionista">
                    <option value="" disabled>Seleziona giorno</option>
                </select>
        </div><br>
        <div class="list" align="center">
                <div class="input-label">
                </div>
                <select style="width: 75%;" ng-options="schedule as schedule.time for schedule in ctrl.data.schedules| filter: { date: ctrl.form.giorno.date, professionista: ctrl.form.professionista.professionista, sede: ctrl.form.sede.sede}" ng-model="ctrl.form.ora" ng-disabled="!ctrl.form.giorno">
                    <option value="" disabled>Seleziona orario</option>
                </select>
        </div><br>
    </div>
</div>
<br>                    
<div align="right">
    <button ng-click="ctrl.submit()"><p>Prenota</p></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a plunkr or reduce your code to the problem.

Comment: @GordonMohrin i've added a snippet

Comment: Did you try running the snippet?  You can't put php in a snippet.

Comment: @Edoardo do you have any console errors?

Comment: @devqon no, there aren't any errors

Comment: @Edoardo you use the `controller as ..` syntax, so you should assign the properties you want to use in the view to the controller: `this.events2 = ..`, `this.submit = function(){}` etc

Comment: @devqon i've tried to use this.submit but nothing changed

Comment: The submit button is on a `<div>` that is not part of the app or the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CHANGE

```
var submit = function () {
    console.log("submit function");
}
```

TO

```
this.submit = function () {
    console.log("submit function");
}
```

submit()'ll work for sure.

Comment: Any luck or still problem is there?

Comment: The problem remained